# add image to gmaps android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gis

Normally in openlayer, if I want to add an image I just create the layer and add it to the map by doing the following:

```
var    map = new OpenLayers.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
```

`var layer = new ImageLayer().add(name, url, envelope, size, this.map);`

with this function i can specify the envelope (norteast , northwest, southeast, southwest boundaries) with WGS84. I can also say the size of the image.

Is there anything similar in android studio for GMAPS? Thanks.

Comment: You can use [Ground Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/groundoverlay)

Comment: Thanks antonio. do you have any sample code or good tutorial website?

Comment: You can see a good example to get started on the [GroundOverlayDemoActivity](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/GroundOverlayDemoActivity.java)

Comment: Thanks for the reference antonio

Comment: Hi antonio, I tried to download the tutorial that you showed me. however it requires google play service 10.2.0. I have updated my sdk to the latest and use api 24 and 25. My Emulator still using 10.0.8 version of play service. Therefore when I run the app, it keeps asking me to upgrade my play service. Can you please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as advised by Antonio in the comment, Ground Overlays should do the trick.